# What kind of electric field would be needed to get a static discharge between two bodies inside vacuum space?

Tags: electrostatics, astrophysics, vacuum, dielectric

I know a perfect vacuum is also the perfect dielectric but I'm  wondering if lightening between two bodies in outer space is possible? In other words, since vacuum is not perfect in outer space but has an energy density effectively about one hydrogen atom per cubic meter homogeneously distributed and with electron-positron pairs constantly popping in and out of the vacuum thus potential charge carriers, how big an electric field would be need to be in order to cause breakdown and create lightening in outer space between two bodies?

If the breakdown E-field of air on Earth at zero altitude is about 30KV per cm, what would be the breakdown value in vacuum space between two charged bodies for a given value of vacuum density? Is there a calculation for that?

I was motivated to ask this question because I have read somewhere that the craters on the moon could be also the result of static discharge by another close by celestial body or comet in the far past?

Comment: I suppose the upper limit would have to be the [Schwinger limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit). Since the spontaneous creation of real pairs could supply the breakdown current, but I would wait for someone to confirm, as an imperfect vacuum like you mention will break down sooner.

Answer (score 0):

The limit depends very much on the material and shape of the bodies. It is fairly easy to get field emission from a tip with atomic diameter, for instance. If I remember correctly the typically required electric field is on the order of 1GV/m. While this sounds like a lot, it is one of the limiting factors in the design of superconducting RF cavities in accelerators. In other words... you are going to rip any known material apart long before you ever get to pair production in vacuum.

That does not mean that we can't explore this regime. Photon-photon colliders are doing just that. If you want to see experimental data then the publications of such facilities are probably the best starting point. Technically even the CMS and ATLAS collaborations are claiming to have observed such events if I remember correctly. Having said that, it is a little bit of a stretch to assign an "electric field" value to individual quantum field events.